# SwiftUI Prevent TabBar from vertical scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Hi i'm using an TabView with the PageTabViewStyle to give me some kind of horizontally scrollable snapchat interface.
My problem is that the TabView doesnt just enable the views to scroll horizontally but also vertically and i would like to prevent that from happening

1. wanted behavior (horizontal scrolling)
2. unwanted behavior (vertical scrolling)

Here is the code to reproduce the behavior

```
import SwiftUI

struct test: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
        }.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
    }
}

struct test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        test()
    }
}
```

I have tried using

```
.onAppear(perform: {
   UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = false
 })
```

one one view

and

```
.onDisappear(perform: {
   UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = true
 })
```

on the others but this does not work as well because the appear/disappear seem to be super buggy

Can't wait to recieve some answers
Best Xaver

Comment: Have you checked this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66817866/14733292

Comment: Yes i have checked that. But sadly this doesnt work for my case as i want to have some screens inside the TabBar to be able to have vertical scrolling.

Comment: Let me know if you get any solutions.